# How select elements between interval

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have html and want to select interval 5  elements from 10'th position. How to do this?

My html:

```
<div class="chaire">
   <img alt="" src="2.gif">

</div>
<div class="chaire">
   <img alt="" src="2.gif">
</div>
<div class="chaire">
   <img alt="" src="2.gif">
</div>
<div class="chaire">
   <img alt="" src="2.gif">
</div>
...
<div class="chaire">
   <img alt="" src="2.gif">
</div>
```

I try with jquery:

```
$(".chaire:gt(10):lt(15)");
```

but it select me div and img tags. But I need div tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Your code does the job just fine, and selects only `<div>` elements.  Take a look at [this example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teQkf/), which finds 5 `<div>` elements after the 10th (`:gt(9):lt(15)`).</strike>

---

The selector you have will only select elements with that class name, in the case of your example HTML, it's just the `<div>` elements.  No `<img>` elements will be selected.  As [rcravens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691854/how-select-elements-between-interval/4691932#4691932) had already pointed out, the two selectors modify the result separately, so you need to use `:lt()` first - `:lt(15):gt(9)`.

Updated example at: http://jsfiddle.net/teQkf/3/.  The next part of the example code finds the `<img>` elements within the result and changes their src to something else.

You're better off using [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice), which is only a single operation on the result and therefore less confusing, not to mention faster:

```
$(".chaire").slice(10,15);
```

[(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/teQkf/1/)

Comment: I don't agree. The :gt(9):lt(15) looks like it is working because there is only 5 more elements in the series. I updated your example to show: http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/teQkf/2/

Comment: @rcravens: yeah, I had just figured that out also.  Swapping the selectors around fixes the problem, so I updated my answer.  I would definitely recommend using `slice` to avoid this sort of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$(".chaire:gt(10):lt(5)");
```

Here is a jFiddle to play around with.

http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/m3j6K/

It looks like chaining the 'gt' and 'lt' selectors means 'lt' is applied to what remains after the 'gt'.

Bob

Comment: If you want to keep the '10' and '15' indices, apply the 'lt' first and the 'gt' second. I updated the jFiddle to include an example of that: http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/m3j6K/1/

Comment: It's worth mentioning that both selectors take zero-based integers as arguments, so 0 is from the first element, 1 is from the second, etc.  Therefore, `:gt(10):lt(5)` actually selects elements 12-15, which is only 4 elements.  See an update to your own example: http://jsfiddle.net/m3j6K/3/