# Why jQuery less than selector doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jquery :lt() selector in the website it ways
"Description: Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set." https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

```
<table border="1">
<tr><td>row0</td></tr>
<tr><td>row1</td></tr>
<tr><td>row2</td></tr>
<tr><td>row3</td></tr>
<tr><td>row4</td></tr>
<tr><td>row5</td></tr>
<tr><td>row6</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to select row3 and row4 so I tried:

```
$("table tr:gt(2):lt(5)").css('background','red');
```

But it doesn't seem to work, it selects row3,row4,row5,row6 any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/v3ro64bf/

edit: this is not a duplicate. I'd like a solution to my specific question. how do I get row3 and row4.

Comment: $("table tr:gt(2):lt(2)").css('background','red'); try this one

Comment: $("table tr:lt(5):gt(2)").css('background','red'); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691854/how-select-elements-between-interval

Comment: [This solution is clever and improves readability](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1137244/1073758).

Comment: wouldn't slice be slower because you're returning ALL elements, I mean. what if my table had thousands of rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indexes for the `:lt` are those returned by the `:gt`. The `:lt` only has 4 elements fed into it, of which *all* of them have an index less than 5, so all of them are matched.

The first `:gt` effectively returns rows 3, 4, 5, and 6, and *only those rows* are matched against by the `:lt`.

If you want to select only rows 3 and 4, you want `:gt(2):lt(2)` to select the first two rows returned by `:gt(2)`:

```js
$("table tr:gt(2):lt(2)").css('background','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr><td>row0</td></tr>
<tr><td>row1</td></tr>
<tr><td>row2</td></tr>
<tr><td>row3</td></tr>
<tr><td>row4</td></tr>
<tr><td>row5</td></tr>
<tr><td>row6</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so LT is essentially the number of rows I want to remove? (when combined with gt)